# How do I download the SDK for iPhone for Leopard?

Tags: iphone, xcode, osx-leopard

I have a Mac with Leopard installed (not Snow Leopard).  I'm trying to start playing around with iPhone development, so I want to download XCode and the iPhone SDK.  I found a version of XCode on Apple's site which runs on Leopard, but it doesn't have the iPhone SDK bundled with it, and I can't find the iPhone SDK anywhere except bundled with the latest version of XCode (and it won't run on Leopard, just Snow Leopard).

Where can I get a copy of the iPhone SDK for Leopard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://chris-fletcher.com/2010/08/28/howto-install-iphone-sdk-2-0-3-1-for-xcode-3-2/

Choose [iPhone SDK 3.1.3 with Xcode 3.1.4 – Leopard].

(I had the same problem.. an old PPC with Mac OS X 10.5 that can't be upgraded to 10.6.2)

This will definitely let you write simple and useful iPhone apps, although I'm not sure about App Store acceptance. Good for 'hello world' and personal stuff, though.

Answer (score 1):

You're out of luck. Current SDK is Snow Leopard only.

Comment: But XCode is still available for Leopard.  It seems bizarre that Apple would allow access to old versions of the development environment, but not old versions of the SDK.

Comment: Xcode for Leopard isn't exactly an "old version". It just doesn't contain the iPhone SDK. The iPhone SDK relies on certain APIs and features that are only available in Snow Leopard. Apple likes to move forward quickly, it's something you just have to come to terms with. And besides, it's not like upgrading to Snow Leopard is expensive or risky. It doesn't have the same price tag difference as versions of Windows do ;)

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Listen to Eiko.  10.5 is no longer supported.

Comment: I have signed up there.  I cannot locate any link to the iPhone SDK for Leopard.